# What does "&" do in this example?

Tags: c++, int, operator-keyword

As the title says, what does `&` do in this example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    int b = 13;
    int c = a & b;

    cout << c << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

My question is what does "&" do to a & b and why is c result 8?

I am currently following [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_operators.htm/), which didn't explain the "&" operator that well.

Comment: It's a bitwise AND operation.

Comment: you could've figured this out with even a [little](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampersand#Programming_languages) searching....

Comment: I know its AND operator but why is c result 8? what does & do with the numbers..

Comment: Think about the binary representations of a and b.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the comments and answer suggest, this is a `bitwise operator`. Bitwise operators treat their operands as groups of bits when they operate on them. A bitwise `and` will, as I'm sure you could guess, `and` two bits, so a truth table would look like:

```
 A | B | A & B
---|---|------
 0 | 0 |   0
 0 | 1 |   0
 1 | 0 |   0
 1 | 1 |   1
```

So when you `and` your `a` and `b`, it will take the binary values of them both, `1010` and `1101` respectively, and `and` each `a` bit with its corresponding `b` bit, so

```
 1010  -a, or 10
&1101  -b, or 13
-----
 1000  -c, or 8
```

Comment: I still don't get it? what do you mean with:  "and and each a bit with its corresponding b bit?" you have to explain it better, im new to working with operators. ( i can read binary though)

Comment: in your example, `a` corresponds to the bit pattern `1010`, or 10. `b` is `1101`. The first bit of `c` will be the first bit of `a` anded with the first bit of `b`, or `a[0]&b[0] = c[0]`, so `c[0] = 1 & 1 = 1` (bits are read left to right). Does this make sense?

Comment: if its read left to right the first bit of a would not be 0 then?  refer to "a[0]&b[0] = c[0]" , and i don't what anded means / does. like i know what + and - does but now anded or &.

Comment: Because `a` is 10, it is made up of an 8, and a 2, so it's binary representation is `1010`. Why do you believe it would be 0?

Comment: im aware of a is 1010 and b is 1101, im with so far.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misspoke in the comments above, bits are read right to left (I always get that mixed up), thus, `a[0]&b[0] = 0 & 1 = 0` (the rightmost column of the and operation in my answer)

Comment: so you can take the first bit (from the right) of a and b and if there is a zero at the place of one of them its equal to 0?

Comment: @hanseN You got it! The only way an `and` operation will be true is if both `a` AND `b` are true.

Comment: if a = 1011 and b = 1101 it would be: 1001? (just making sure im right), thanks for helping ;)

Comment: @hanseN Yes sir, that's spot on. Take a look at (http://www.miniwebtool.com/bitwise-calculator/) if you want to run more tests for yourself (just select binary for the input instead of decimal). Also, if this answer is what you're looking for, please accept it as the right answer (you'll also get a small rep boost for doing it) :)

Comment: Done! and yes i will try that website ;)

Answer (score 1):

The & is a bitwise AND operator. Se this link for more information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C#Bitwise_AND_.22.26.22